Cloudinary asking for env variable I provided: A Cloudinary Cloud name is required, please make sure NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME is set
I've uploaded my nextjs app to vercel, cloudinary doesn't seem to throw any errors at me and is storing my images just and I can display them on the app just fine.
When I push my commit to github/vercel I get this error stack
https://codefile.io/f/ezzy3n1Pzd
Error: A Cloudinary Cloud name is required, please make sure NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME is set and configured in your environment.

Here's where I configure my cloudinary service:
import {v2 as cloudinary} from "cloudinary";
//import "dotenv/config.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config();

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET    
})

export const POST = async(request: Request) => {
    const body = (await request.json()) as {paramsToSign: Record<string, string>};
    const {paramsToSign} = body;
    const signature = cloudinary.utils.api_sign_request(
        paramsToSign,
        process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET as string
    );
    return Response.json({signature});
}

...and this is part of my .env file:

NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET= "*****************************"
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME= "*********"
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_API_KEY= "************************"
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_URL= "********************************************** ****************************"

CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET= "***********************"
CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME= "************"
CLOUDINARY_API_KEY= "**************"

keys are edited, obviously
I have dotenv installed, I tried passing the environment variables both in COULDINARY_ and NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_ formats, doesn't work...

Most likely you are not correctly importing the .ENV file, if you console log the variables do they pass through? I would take a look at the scope if they don't and make sure the .env is accessible.

@PixelCook I logged them in one of the TSX components and I got the right values ... but when I try logging them in the POST function I mentioned in the OP I don't get any log, even when I try to log something like "hi". Guessing it has to do with the function being async? The POST request works fine otherwise...

But if you log the variables in that page before the functions is called are the results correct?
